# Avoid accessing backbone view with or without hash in url

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js

I have implemented Facebook login using passport in my application.

```
app.get('/index', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
      res.render('/', {});
});

function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
      if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next(); }
      res.redirect('/')
}
```

In the front end I am using backbone for single page application, without a hash in url.

```
Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true });
```

When I enter `/index` in the url, it's redirecting to login page (which is perfect). But, when I enter `/#index`, `indexView` is loading.

What is the proper way to handle such conditions? I want to avoid having the user access any of my view, with or without hash in url, if they are not logged in.

Comment: Can you provide more information about the routes ?